# managing stored file permissions on ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, file-permissions, laravel-5.5

I have a laravel 5.5 app deployed to an ec2 instance managed by elasticbeanstalk. One of the app's functions involve taking a form-uploaded zip archive of course documents, unzipping the archive, and storing the files in storage/app/public.

```
public function updateCourseFolder($file)
{
    $folderName = explode('.', $file->getClientOriginalName())[0];
    $zip = Zip::open($file); //The Zip class here is an instance of zanysoft/laravel-zip
    $zip->extract(storage_path('app/public/courses/'.$this->id));
    Storage::putFileAs('public/courses/'.$this->id.'/archives/', $file, Carbon::now()->timestamp.'.zip');
    $this->update(['folder_path' => 'storage/courses/'.$this->id.'/'.$folderName ]);
}
```

The problem I'm having is that on the ec2 instance, the files and directories are being created with permissions that immediately become inaccessable to the webapp -- on form submit, the same controller action that stores the zip kicks out a permission denied error when it tries to access the files it just created.

Looking at the unzipped file details, they're being created with the webapp user/group (consistent with everything else in the app) but with "d-wxr----t" permissions compared to "drwxrwxr-x" permissions for most everything else in the app.

This is not an issue I can recreate locally at all, just on my AWS deployment.